# template specialization for all iterators of std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization, type-traits

I have traits class, saying:

```
template <class T>
struct KeyValueTraits
{
    typedef typename T::key_t key_t;
    typedef typename T::value_t value_t;
}
```

Now I would like to declare specialization of this traits for all iterators of `std::map`

```
template < typename... Args >
struct KeyValueTraits<typename std::map<Args...>::iterator >
{
    typedef std::map<Args...> target_t;
    typedef typename target_t::key_type key_t;
    typedef typename target_t::mapped_type value_t;
};
```

Compiler raises an error:

> error C2764: 'Args': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization

So how to declare traits-type for all possible `std::map<...>::iterator`?

Comment: You can't. Not the way you are trying to do at any rate. There is no way to extract container type out of an iterator. You can try using `first` and `second` instead (needs C++11).

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  There are solutions that will work for any iterator that has `std::pair < const K, V >` as a value type.  Once you have the iteraror, it's not always possible to get information about the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution (it changes the KeyValueTraits template signature because it doesn't seem possible otherwise).

```
template <class T, class = void>
struct KeyValueTraits
{
    typedef typename T::key_t key_t;
    typedef typename T::value_t value_t;
};

template <class MapIter>
struct KeyValueTraits<MapIter, 
                      typename std::enable_if<
                         sizeof(std::declval<MapIter>()->first) && 
                         sizeof(std::declval<MapIter>()->second)
                      >::type>
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<MapIter>()->first) key_t;
    typedef decltype(std::declval<MapIter>()->second) value_t;
};
```

Comment: n.m. - sorry but... the type of the key, in maps, isn't `key_type`? More: not sure but I suspect that the OP ask for `value_t` but he really want the `mapped_type`

Answer (score 2):

You use variadic template parameters, so I suppose you can accept a C++11 solution.

I propose the following (not really great), based on template specialization, solution.

Take in count that the type of the key, in `std::map<>`, isn't `key_t` but `key_type` and that the type of the value isn't `value_t` but `mapped_type`.

```
#include <map>

template <typename X>
struct with_kt
 { 
   template <typename Y = X>
   static constexpr bool getValue (int, typename Y::key_type * = nullptr)
    { return true; }

   static constexpr bool getValue (long)
    { return false; }

   static constexpr bool value { getValue(0) };
 };

template <typename T, bool = with_kt<T>::value>
struct KeyValueTraits;

template <typename T>
struct KeyValueTraits<T, true>
 {
   using key_t   = typename T::key_type;
   using value_t = typename T::mapped_type;
 };

template <typename T>
struct KeyValueTraits<T, false>
 {
   using pair_t  = decltype(* std::declval<T>());

   using key_t   = typename std::remove_const<
                      decltype(std::declval<pair_t>().first)>::type;
   using value_t = decltype(std::declval<pair_t>().second);
 };


using mil = std::map<int,long>;

int main()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<KeyValueTraits<mil>::key_t,
                              KeyValueTraits<mil::iterator>::key_t
                              >::value, "!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<KeyValueTraits<mil>::value_t,
                              KeyValueTraits<mil::iterator>::value_t
                              >::value, "!!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<KeyValueTraits<mil>::key_t,
                              KeyValueTraits<mil::const_iterator>::key_t
                              >::value, "!!!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<KeyValueTraits<mil>::key_t,
                              KeyValueTraits<mil::reverse_iterator>::key_t
                              >::value, "!!!!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<KeyValueTraits<mil>::key_t,
                              KeyValueTraits<mil::const_reverse_iterator>::key_t
                              >::value, "!!!!!");
 }
```

Comment: Thank for his solution +1, just corrected `mapped_type` mistake.